# Spring Boot YAML Auto Data Source Configuration Issue - Data Source URL not picked up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, microservices

Currently, We are creating a spring boot project for our newer modules.

Technology We have used as follows :

1. Java 1.8
2. Maven 3.5.2
3. Spring Boot: 1.5.6.RELEASE (spring-boot-starter-parent)

public class Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;
```

}

application.properties

- spring.datasource.url=**jdbc:oracle:XXX:@XXX:XXX/XXX**
- spring.datasource.username=XXX
- spring.datasource.password=XXX
- spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

application.yml

- spring:

  - profiles:
  - active: "dev"
  - main:

    ### - banner-mode: "off"
- spring:

  - profiles: dev
  - datasource:

    - url:**jdbc:oracle:XXX:@XXX:XXX/XXX**
    - username:XXX
    - password:XXX
    - driver-class-name:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

When we are adding data source information as properties file the application working as expected. But information as YAML means showing below error.

**ERROR**

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testapplication': **Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'datasource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource** [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: **Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "dev" are currently active)**.

Comment: Can't help much without source code... Also please try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what is your spring:profiles:active property value in yml?

Comment: spring:
  profiles:
    active: "dev"
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"

---

Comment: do you have a space after colon for `driver-class-name:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` ? If not that is wrong. You need to have a space after colon according to yml convention

Comment: there is no space@pvpkiran

Comment: thanks a lot @pvpkiran. After giving space its working fine..

Comment: Sure.. @pvpkiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yml standards dictate us to specify a space after colon(`:`). Please have a look at the [documentation](http://driver-class-name:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
  Change your yml like this and It should work fine.

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
     url: jdbc:oracle:XXX:@XXX:XXX/XXX
     username: XXX
     password: XXX
     driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```